# How to completely eliminate the reverse beep on a 2012 Prius

Tags: obd-ii, computer, prius, elm-327

I followed [these instructions](http://www.dogberrypatch.com/archives/programming-a-prius-to-disable-the-backup-beep/) (same as described in [method 3 of a wikiHow page](https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Reverse-Beep-in-a-Toyota-Prius)) to "disable" the reverse beep on my 2012 Prius using a bluetooth OBD2 adapter and a mobile app to connect to it.

Type: `AT SH 7c0` (hit ‘Send’)
Returns: `OK`

Type: `21ac` (hit ‘Send’)
Returns: `61 AC 00` (00 means continuous reverse beep)

Type: `3bac40` (hit ‘Send’)

This resulted, as the post described, in the car making only a single beep when traveling in reverse.

Is there a code to send that will completely eliminate the reverse beep?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While it may be annoying to you to have the beep, my suggestion is to not remove it completely. The beep is there, not for you, but those around you. If you put your Prius in reverse and hit someone because they don't hear you moving and you don't see them, you could be liable for hurting someone. When I say "liable" I mean responsible, both civilly (monetarily) and criminally (hitting a pedestrian). Just not a good situation, IMHO.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The reverse beep on a Prius actually is only inside - it is not audible outside. https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Prius-cars-beep-on-the-inside-when-in-reverse-and-not-on-the-outside

Comment: Fair enough ... you can probably tell I don't own one, eh? :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ;) I do think it is an odd choice by Toyota. it would have made more sense to me if it were on the outside.

Comment: Is it a proximity sensor beeping or is it just a constant beep?

Comment: @GabeWisneski originally the functionality was a constant beep when in reverse, as described in the first link in the question. It is not related to a proximity sensor.